# $6\times 6$ linearly independent matrices for Hamiltonian fourier expansion

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, group-theory, representation-theory

I want to use the Slater-Koster method to Fourier expand a $6 \times 6$ Hamiltonian and for this, I need 36 linearly independent basis matrices. In two dimensions, we use Pauli matrices, and in 4 dimensions we use gamma matrices but I couldn't find anything with $6 \times 6$ dimensions in the literature. Does anybody have any idea? Any help would be appreciated.
Reference: Group theory and applications to condensed matter, Dresselhaus, page 389

Comment: Basic due diligence reveals:[this from Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedGell-MannMatrix.html) or [this from Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices).  The wiki entry contains additional references.